# Можно использовать наблюдающие методы set{} get{} без использования классов и наследования?

Tags: swift, классы, переменные, методы, переопределение

Можно использовать наблюдающие методы `set{} get{}` без использования классов и наследования? Не судите строго я новичок в  swift.

```
class z{
var xu:String="z"  
}

class x:z{
var x:Int=9
var zr:String="zoo"
 override var xu:String{
   set{zr=newValue}
   get {return "\(zr)=>\(x)"}
 }
  }

  var ww=x()
 print(ww.xu)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get и set - не наблюдающие методы. Наблюдающие это `willSet` и `didSet`. И все их можно использовать без классов. Попробуйте пример в playground:

```
var _b: String = "test" {
    willSet {
        print("_b value will be changed to: \(newValue)")
    }
    didSet {
        print("_b value set from oldValue: \(oldValue) to newValue: \(_b)")
    }
}

var b: String {
    get {
        print("get _b value: \(_b)")
        return _b
    }
    set {
        print("set new _b value: \(newValue)")
        _b = newValue
    }
}

b = "NewTest"
let a = b
```

Разбор вывода:

> set new _b value: NewTest
>   _b value will be changed to: NewTest
>   _b value set from oldValue: test to newValue: NewTest
>   get _b value: NewTest

Когда присваиваем значение в строке `b = "NewTest"` вызываеются `set` b > `willSet` _b > `didSet` _b
В строке `let a = b` вызывается `get` b

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за доброту ко мне ) а что означает  _b

Comment: @LifeБедняка просто имя переменной.

Comment: тойсь нижний регистр под переменной просто так ?)

Comment: @LifeБедняка так исторически сложилось. Подобные варианты использую когда условная _b - private переменная, а b - computed property через которую взаимодействуем с _b. Пошло от Objective-C с его iVar. Как-то так, не умею особо объяснять.

Comment: Скажу вам честно, не со всем понял ваш пример, сейчас я его разбираю, если вам не сложно можете показать на примере моего.class z{
var xu:String="z"  
}

class x:z{
var x:Int=9
var zr:String="zoo"
 override var xu:String{
   set{zr=newValue}
   get {return "\(zr)=>\(x)"}
 }
  }

  var ww=x()
 print(ww.xu)

Comment: @LifeБедняка замените b на Ваш xu, _b на zr и будет то же самое по механике работы.